# Increase number of buttons for XTEST pointer?

Tags: xserver

I'm playing around with evrouter and I'm getting an error when trying to generate a button press for button number greater than 10. My Logitech Mouse reports 20 buttons but the Virtual core XTEST pointer only reports 10.

```
$ xinput get-button-map "Logitech Performance MX"
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 2 11 12 2 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
$ xinput get-button-map "Virtual core XTEST pointer"
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

How can I increase the number of buttons for the XTEST pointer?

(X.Org X Server 1.19.2)